Can you generate a CSR on behalf of a user?
For an internal API, one of the capabilities is allowing a user to deploy an internal-facing website. Normally, for these websites a cert is issued by the company CA and the user/team must generate a CSR locally and then supply it when requesting the cert manually.
When looking to automate the process, I want to know if it's possible/recommended to generate the CSR on the API server so that the user doesn't need to generate or manage any keys themselves.

In order to use a certificate for authentication one has to have a certificate which includes the public key and then the matching private key. The private key needs to be private - as the name suggest - since with this key it is possible to impersonate the identity of the certificate.
For generating a CSR one needs a private key. This means that if you create a CSR for another user, then the private key is no longer private to the user. That's why this is not recommended. It is still possible though, but to reduce exposure of the key you should then distribute the private key to the user in a secure way and make sure to securely remove any remaining copies of the private key at the CA or in communication systems (i.e. in an email) after the user has received the key.
If this is a private infrastructure where the ones managing the CA also manage the rest of the infrastructure, then they might have access to the private key no matter if the CSR was generated by the users or by the CA.  In this specific situation is might be tolerable to create the CSR for other users since it does not seem to add much more risks. But while tolerable it is still not the recommended way.
And for really secure systems the private key should be created inside a hardware security module (HSM) and never be transferred out of this HSM. In this case it needs to be created by the one owning the HSM and cannot created by someone else.

Yes, this is all private infra. The private keys are stored and managed via company AWS so the key being private to the user doesn't seem necessary if they don't own the resources signed/generated with it. Regarding best practices, in this case, isn't it more secure to not rely on a single user keeping the key safe and letting the API manage its storage and access via AWS PKI management tools?

@swigganicks: I'm confused. In your question you talk about "allowing a user to deploy an internal-facing website". But in your comment you say that ".... if they [users] don't own the resources signed/generated with it.". This makes it unclear who has what responsibilities. In any case - it does not change that the private key should be kept private to the party who is responsible for the key, whatever this is in your case.

Yes, the company will own the resources (the website being deployed) even if the user is the one that deployed it. We would like to shift the ownership burden to an application (our API) so that an individual user does not need to create and manage keys for the CSR. This way, the API app team is responsible for the keys and CSR. But ultimately, I think I understand what you're saying.
